# qz-tray Esc/pos Qr code not Generating, how to fix this problem?

Tags: javascript, qr-code, thermal-printer, escpos, qz-tray

- i've Just copy the qz-tray ESC/POS qr code program.
  [qz-tray esc/pos qrcode](https://qz.io/wiki/raw-legacy#escpos-qr-code)
- printer works perfectly and connection also done successfully.
- But qr code is not generated. printer print Like this...

  ```
    1P0https://qz.io 1A11C 1E0
  ```
- printer print this single line only. how to solve this?

  **var config = qz.configs.create("POS-80", { encoding: 'ISO-8859-1' });**

  ```
   // The QR data
   var qr = 'https://qz.io';

   // The dot size of the QR code
   var dots = '\x09';

   // Some proprietary size calculation
   var qrLength = qr.length + 3;
   var size1 =  String.fromCharCode(qrLength % 256);
   var size0 = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(qrLength / 256));

   var data = [ 
      // <!-- BEGIN QR DATA -->
      '\x1D' + '\x28' + '\x6B' + '\x04' + '\x00' + '\x31' + '\x41' + '\x32' + '\x00',    // <Function 165> select the model (model 2 is widely supported)
      '\x1D' + '\x28' + '\x6B' + '\x03' + '\x00' + '\x31' + '\x43' + dots,               // <Function 167> set the size of the module
      '\x1D' + '\x28' + '\x6B' + '\x03' + '\x00' + '\x31' + '\x45' + '\x30',             // <Function 169> select level of error correction (48,49,50,51) printer-dependent
      '\x1D' + '\x28' + '\x6B' + size1 + size0 + '\x31' + '\x50' + '\x30' + qr,          // <Function 080> send your data (testing 123) to the image storage area in the printer
      '\x1D' + '\x28' + '\x6B' + '\x03' + '\x00' + '\x31' + '\x51' +'\x30',              // <Function 081> print the symbol data in the symbol storage area
      '\x1D' + '\x28' + '\x6B' + '\x03' + '\x00' + '\x31' + '\x52' +'\x30',              // <Function 082> Transmit the size information of the symbol data in the symbol storage area
      // <!-- END QR DATA -->
   ];

   qz.print(config, data).catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
  ```

Comment: Which make and model is the printer?  If Xprinter: If you use the Xprinter "XPrinter Receipt Printer Test Tool for Windows", does `Advanced > Print 2D Barcode` button work for this printer? https://www.xprintertech.com/test-tool.  If so, it might help to capture the raw data being sent so that we can reverse engineer it.

Comment: printer model is POS Thermal printer. 80mm

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information, but this is neither a make nor a model.  Do you have the manufacturer information to share?  Each hardware is different, so knowing who makes the hardware is important to identifying the devices capabilities.

Comment: Hi,sorry,i'll give the information about it.   model: 260IV SU CLASSIC,  name: KVPOS thermal printer, command:ESCPOS,

Comment: [printer Details pdf](https://5.imimg.com/data5/SELLER/Doc/2021/2/MN/OI/SZ/17791178/kvpos-therma-printer.pdf)

Comment: Thank you.  I've emailed http://www.kvbusinesssolutions.in for technical help with this.  I've asked them for a QR code printing example so that we can adapt this example to be used by QZ Tray.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to help me. @tresf

Comment: hi,  @tresf if any response form them.

Comment: No, not yet. :/

Comment: If you can obtain another QR code example for ESC/POS that works with your printer, we'd be happy to adopt it to the above example. :)